# std::vectors to arrow::table

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

I've looked through the Apache Arrow docs but I can't find a clean way of converting equal length `std::vector`s into an `arrow::Array` and then an `arrow::Table`. Here's the code in question.

```
#include <vector>
#include <arrow/array.h>
#include <arrow/table.h>

const std::vector<double> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
const std::vector<bool> b = {true, false, false, true, true};

auto schema = arrow::schema({arrow::field("a", arrow::float64()), arrow::field("b", arrow::boolean())});

std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> array_a(N, arrow::float64());
std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> array_b(N, arrow::boolean());

// how to store the contents of the vectors a and b into array_a and array_b, resp.
// ...?

std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table = arrow::Table::Make(schema, {array_a, array_b});
```

Comment: perhaps these docs will help https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/arrays.html

Comment: Thanks @Robin Dillen. I'd missed those docs.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/arrays.html),you can use a builder for this:

```cpp
const std::vector<double> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
const std::vector<bool> b = {true, false, false, true, true};

auto schema = arrow::schema({arrow::field("a", arrow::float64()), arrow::field("b", arrow::boolean())});


arrow::DoubleBuilder aBuilder;
PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(aBuilder.AppendValues(a));

arrow::BooleanBuilder bBuilder;
PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(bBuilder.AppendValues(b));

std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> array_a, array_b;
ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(array_a, aBuilder.Finish());
ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(array_b, bBuilder.Finish());

std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table = arrow::Table::Make(schema, {array_a, array_b});
```